# Combining two hashing functions

Tags: hash, keys, key-distribution

I have been working on a Bloom Filter implementation recently and after a discussion with a co-worker about how many hashing functions to use I told him I was limited with using hashing functions that are already implemented and didn't want to risk the loss of distribution if I derive hashing functions from them.

We can assume that the distribution of any hashing function is not 100% perfect. It's very good for many, but not perfect. **Is there any existing literature that describes the loss of distribution?** I am not using the hashing functions for cryptographic purposes directly, because in a bloom filter it's only used as an index, and it's the distribution is the most important for my needs - but I assume they are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of a bloom filter you need a number of hash functions. Cryptographic hash functions are designed so that changing a single bit in the input should change many (around 1/2) of the output bits.

So, say you have a good hash function $h$ (e.g., SHA256 though MD5 should work for your purposes too) a good option for you would be to use use:

$h_1(m)=h("1" || m)$
$h_2(m)=h("2" || m)$
$\vdots$
$h_n(m)=h("n" || m)$

Where $||$ is concatenation. Then you only need one hash function. This is basically what they are doing in [this java implementation](https://github.com/MagnusS/Java-BloomFilter/blob/master/src/com/skjegstad/utils/BloomFilter.java).

> Is there any existing literature that describes the loss of distribution?

Not that I am aware of. But think about it this way, if there were a significant change from the uniform distribution computable in a reasonable amount of time we wouldn't use the hash function for cryptographic purposes.

Now, is there some sort of attack you are worried about?

Comment: Not a specific attack but I am curious if anyone has done the math. My "gut" tells me that it's a compound of some kind, and we can assume that a good hashing algo might be 0.99 "distributed" but I am concerned with compounding like 0.99 * 0.99 * 0.99 ...